# 1500+ duplicate queries via get_option function (query monitor)

Tags: wp-query, functions

I'm having a huge performance issue once I'm logged into Wordpress. Query Monitor says it's doing over 1500+ duplicated queries with the get_option function executing this query:

```
SELECT option_name, option_value 
FROM wp_options
WHERE autoload = 'yes'
```

I'm running on cloudways, cleaned my wp_options table, and searched Google from top to bottom but can't find the solution.

I've disabled plugins, renewed the admin and includes folder and so on.

Any input would be great!

Answer (score 0):

To everyone experiencing the same issue, I have seem to solved it by doing the following:

1. Get a clean copy of WordPress
2. Replace the WP-Content folder
3. Copy your original/existing themes, plugins and upload folder back into that new wp-content
4. That's it... I know, it makes no sense but it somehow did the job.